# WebBrowser Library Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python Webbrowser library has the new varibale for its open where, by default, it will open up a file in the same browser window. Is there a way to open up the same file in the same TAB. Like whatever the current page that is open on the browser, redirect that page the specified url.

current code is:

```
import webbrowser
url = "http://www.google.com"
webbrowser.open(url)
```

but this opens in a new tab but I want it to open in my current tab. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as adding new=0 like this:
`webbrowser.open(url, new=0)`

> Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible.

according to:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the Webbrowser module.

It is possible with Selenium module though
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

download the module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sst/0.2.4

In the code:

```
from sst.actions import * 
go_to('url')
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that and installed sst but the go_to function isnt working. am i missing something? I used the exact code but with http://google.com as the url

Comment: does the import statement work? try just running: import sst.actions

Comment: maybe python cant find the directory